# Not able to make Windows as a default OS in GRUB2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

## This is how my grub.cfg looks like:

```
 1 # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
  2 # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
  3 # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
  4 #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
  5 
  6 GRUB_DEFAULT=2
  7 #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  8 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  9 GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
 10 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
 11 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
 12 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
 13 
 14 # Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
 15 # This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
 16 # the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
 17 #GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
 18 
 19 # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
 20 #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
 21 
 22 # The resolution used on graphical terminal
 23 # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
 24 # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
 25 #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
 26 
 27 # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
 28 #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
 29 
 30 # Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
 31 #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
 32 
 33 # Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
 34 #GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

==========================================================================

[image: this is how my GRUB menu looks like]

Even after making the default = 2 which corresponds to Windows...it's loading Linux...i have done sudo update-grub after this change.. EFI entries has been cleaned up and old linux images has been removed....any help? thanks in advance. I want to make Windows as a default O/S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
grub-customizer
```

Using these commands i am able resolve this issue